# TVS diode specs - clamping voltage lower than breakdown voltage?

Tags: tvs, diode-clamp, reverse-breakdown

Having read [this app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slvae37) (and a few others) and quite a number of TVS datasheets, I came across one that is bugging me a bit.

All of the TVS datasheets that I have read so far describe the the following concept (below curve is for a unidirectional TVS, but the same principle applies for a bidirectional TVS):

[image: TVS curve]

Thus, to generalize, the following ***seems*** to always be true:

\$V_{RWM} < V_{BR} < V_{CLAMP} \$

Then I read the datasheet of the [Vishay XMC7K24CA](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/xmc7k24ca.pdf) and saw this:

[image: TVS specs]

From that table, \$V_{CL, max} < V_{BR, min}\$ (and \$V_{BR, max}\$ for that matter). This does not correspond with the general TVS curve above. How is this possible?

---

**EDIT:** Yet another [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DESD18VS1BLP3.pdf) (DIODES DESD18VS1BLP3) that shows the same:

[image: TVS specs 2]

I am definitely misunderstanding something here...

Comment: It can happen. I think it's called "snapback". Google app notes about that. There are also two terminal thryistors that take this to the extreme by breaking down to conduct at a very low voltage to crowbar.

Comment: Take a look at figure 5 of the DIODES datasheet. This is where the higher breakdown voltage at 1mA comes from i would assume. Maybe somebody can explain the graph?

Comment: Found a good article regarding the snapback described above:
https://blog.semtech.com/tvs-its-just-a-diode-right-part-two

Comment: This is indeed the "snapback" effect (a.k.a. thyristor-like characteristic) and seems to be quite common in some TVS devices. I learned something new today :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This device has a thyristor-like latching characteristic. Here is a simulation of the SPICE model supplied by the manufacturer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a thyristor-like characteristic (also called "snapback") of the device. I first had to do some reading to understand this, but now it all makes sense.

Comment: The datasheet is less than helpful and I couldn't find any more information from [Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/diodes/protection-tvs-esd/xclampr/)  on it, other than the SPICE model. They also don't appear to use the "snapback" term, but it's definitely a useful addition to the lexicon, thanks to @DKNguyen for that.

Comment: You are exactly right. I was searching for "snapback" term and couldn't find it, even in other similar datasheets as well! That is part of the reason why I was so confused. Although, I must admit, I did not know about "snapback" TVS diodes up to now. I learned a lot through your answer & comments to this question.